# Why is my user name (number) displayed in the search box in Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: support

I am using Stack Overflow from my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Why do I get my username displayed in the search box in the top right top?

> [image]

Comment: This is true everywhere for every browser.  On top of that, what exactly are you requesting?

Comment: This is _as designed_.

Comment: But it is not displayed in the chrome, only displays in the firefox

Answer (score 3):

This is done to make it easy for you to do a search within your own posts, without you having to type your userid manually (and remembering the correct syntax for that advanced search option).

This feature is available on all SE sites across all supported browsers.

If you want to do a regular search from your user page, clear it or browse to another page.

Comment: But it the name automatically disappears it will be easy, rather than press the Backspace button

Comment: If it disappeared automatically, it would be useless. Type Ctrl+A to get rid of it with a single backspace.